# I'm trying to make two monsters battle, given the user input, and keep getting a global error?

Tags: python, jython

```
def globalSuit():
  global Affinity1
  global HP1
  global AD1
  global Affinity2
  global HP2
  global AD2

def getmonsterData():
 monster1 =  raw_input("Enter the Monster 1's Affinity|HP|AD> ")
 x = monster1.index('|')
 y = monster1.index('|',x+1)
 Affinity1 = monster1[:x]
 HP1 = monster1[x+1:y]
 AD1 = monster1[y+1:]
 printNow(Affinity1+"|"+HP1+"|"+AD1)

 monster2 =  raw_input("Enter the Monster 2's Affinity|HP|AD> ")
 x = monster2.index('|')
 y = monster2.index('|',x+1)
 Affinity2 = monster2[:x]
 HP2 = monster2[x+1:y]
 AD2 = monster2[y+1:]
 printNow(Affinity2+"|"+HP2+"|"+AD2)
 battleNow();

def battleNow():
 if (AD1 > AD2):
    printNow("Monster 1 is stronger")
 if (AD1 < AD2):
    printNow("Monster 2 is stronger")
```

The main problem at hand is that when i run this, ideally the user will input the Monster data 1 and 2 is this

```
def getmonsterData():
     monster1 =  raw_input("Enter the Monster 1's Affinity|HP|AD> ")
     x = monster1.index('|')
     y = monster1.index('|',x+1)
     Affinity1 = monster1[:x]
     HP1 = monster1[x+1:y]
     AD1 = monster1[y+1:]
     printNow(Affinity1+"|"+HP1+"|"+AD1)

     monster2 =  raw_input("Enter the Monster 2's Affinity|HP|AD> ")
     x = monster2.index('|')
     y = monster2.index('|',x+1)
     Affinity2 = monster2[:x]
     HP2 = monster2[x+1:y]
     AD2 = monster2[y+1:]
     printNow(Affinity2+"|"+HP2+"|"+AD2)`
```

and then as you can see towards the bottom of the code i also feed it to go to the next method battleNow();
which ideally would feed it the monster information 1 and 2 that was inputted in the last method, then i could take these 3 variables, AFF|HP|AD, and i suppose i in the battleNow method i could make some if/else statements saying which one is stronger based on the Affinity factor/their HP/ and their AD

```
 if (AD1 > AD2):
    printNow("Monster 1 is stronger")
 if (AD1 < AD2):
    printNow("Monster 2 is stronger")`
```

this will determine which monster is stronger, but i just cant seem to get it to recognize what AD1:AD2/Hp1:Hp2/aff1:aff2 are outside of getMonsterData();

the error i get is,

```
"======= Loading Progam =======
Enter the Monster 1's Affinity|HP|AD> Earth|50|10
Earth|50|10
Enter the Monster 2's Affinity|HP|AD> Water|55|10
Water|55|10
The error was:AD1
Name not found globally.
A local or global name could not be found. You need to define the function or variable before you try to use it in any way."
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function getMonsterData() or your main should call the function globalSuit().
The error you are getting is when you call the function battleNow() your variables are not defined global yet.
example of fix:

```
def getmonsterData():
     globalSuit()
     monster1 =  raw_input("Enter the Monster 1's Affinity|HP|AD> ")
     x = monster1.index('|')
     y = monster1.index('|',x+1)
     Affinity1 = monster1[:x]
     HP1 = monster1[x+1:y]
     AD1 = monster1[y+1:]
     printNow(Affinity1+"|"+HP1+"|"+AD1)

     monster2 =  raw_input("Enter the Monster 2's Affinity|HP|AD> ")
     x = monster2.index('|')
     y = monster2.index('|',x+1)
     Affinity2 = monster2[:x]
     HP2 = monster2[x+1:y]
     AD2 = monster2[y+1:]
     printNow(Affinity2+"|"+HP2+"|"+AD2)`
```

Comment: this didn't seem to do the fix.. i changed my code to def globalSuit():
  global Affinity1
  global HP1
  global AD1
  global Affinity2
  global HP2
  global AD2
  
def getmonsterData():
 globalSuit();
 monster1 =  raw_input("Enter the Monster 1's Affinity|HP|AD> ")
 x = monster1.index('|')
 y = monster1.index('|',x+1)




def battleNow():
 if (AD1 > AD2):

Comment: strange. why do you want to declare the global vars in a function, why not declaring them in the main or outside of every function ?

Comment: i just know the problem is its not recognizing these three variables outside of getMonsterData(); i thought making a method and filling it with the global commands for those variables that it would work for battleNow(); and other methods i intend on implementing?

Answer (score 0):

All i had to do was instead of making a seperate method for my global vars, to put it in the main, getmonsterData();

i think i've solved what i needed.. thanks a lot everyone!